# Gradle dependency not created within Gradle cache?

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, cxf

Within my dependencies of my module's `.gradle` file I have the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:2.7.18'
}
```

I am linking to [this repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle/2.7.18)

My project is building ok and other dependencies are generated with the `Gradle cache`. However whenever I look for this dependency's folder within cache, in

```
 artifacts-26>filestore
```

it is not there.

My understanding of gradle is quite limited, I dont know why would this would not be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloaded artifacts from external repositories go here by default:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/<group>/<artifact>/<version>/<SHA1-checksum-of-module>
```

An example for `cxf-core-3.1.3.jar` downloaded dependency below:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.1.3/dc1e652736d770dc34dcacbac2279055e7fce000
```

**Note**: This is using Gradle 2.8. Some older versions of Gradle might have a slightly different structure after `~/.gradle/caches/`

Comment: Thanks: I am having trouble finding class:  "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" ?

Comment: Can I download this class separately and put it in the jar? Thanks alot

Comment: Sorry I have found it, how can I run this class from the cmd line?